# Cocoa WebView display permission dialog for js navigator.geolocation.getCurrentLocation()

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

In your standard desktop browser like Safari or Chrome, when you navigate to a site such as maps.google.com and click on the 'my location' button, a message appears asking you if you'd like to give permission to the website to use your GPS/wifi triangulation position.

My question is, how do you detect such an event and show a dialog to a user when using a standard Cocoa (desktop) WebView object?  I've tried implementing all of the various delegate methods and none of them seem to catch this javascript event.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

It just fails silently.  How do I ask the user for location sharing permission?

Comment: Did you see [this question on Stack Overflow][1]? It looks like that could be a solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505617/how-can-i-set-my-latitude-and-longitude-for-debugging-the-geolocation-api-with-g

Comment: I'm marking your answer correct, but it is the comment that led me down the right path.  I still have plenty of questions, but at least now I can intercept the geolocation js request and do something about it in Obj-C.

Comment: I tried adding my comment as a new answer, but StackOverflow automatically converted it to a comment. Anyway, thanks! Glad I could help.

Comment: @andrew, can you please let me know how you were able to intercept the call? I need to make it work in web view for my app .

Comment: @Sagrian, It was a client project and I no longer have the source. I think you have to rewrite the javascript function getCurrentPosition so that it talks to Obj-C.  Then you can use Core Location to get the GPS position and feed that data back into the webview using a callback.  It took some tinkering around but I eventually got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just digging in some [private headers](http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-6531.9/mac/WebView/WebUIDelegatePrivate.h) I found this method:

- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)sender frame:(WebFrame *)frame requestGeolocationPermission:(WebGeolocation *)geolocation securityOrigin:(WebSecurityOrigin *)origin;

Did you try to see if it gets called? You probably won't get this past the App Store though, since it is a private API call.

Comment: This has to clear an App Store review, so no private methods.

Comment: just tested: it does not get called; at least not from the WebUIDelegate. Maybe one has to register as WebUIPrivateDelegate...